# Text Field - Text goes below the IME in LazyColum jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, ime

I have a list which for each item wraps a form with four input fields, when i click on an input field the keyboard is opened and overlap of input field. Have you faced this problem before?

**Expected behavior**: The input field is moved above the keyboard.

**This is how my screen looks visually**

[image]

And this is how looks in code:

```
setContent {
                ConsumerTheme {
                    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
                    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
                    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    
                    Scaffold(
                        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
                        topBar = {
                            Toolbar()
                        },
                    ) { innerPadding ->
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .padding(innerPadding)
                        ) {
                            listState.firstVisibleItemIndex
                            LazyColumn(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .weight(1f)
                                    .scrollable(scrollState, Orientation.Vertical),
                                state = listState
                            ) {
    
                                item {
                                    SetupListRowStepper()
                                }
    
                                item {
                                    // Divider wit label
                                    DividerWithLabel(LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.you))
                                }
    
                                item {
                                    // list row avatar (Client)
                                    ClientProfile()
                                }
    
                                // Guest list
                                item {
                                    SetupGuestList()
                                }
                            }
                            NextCustomButton(
                                formState = groupBookingViewModel.guestState.value.areAllValidationFieldsValid,
                                processPreBookingAttempt = groupBookingViewModel::processPreBookingAttempt,
                                saveGroupTelemetry = ::saveGroupTelemetry
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

My `SetupGuestList()` is a list as well:

```
Column {
        repeat(numOfGuests) {
            GuestFormItem(
                it,
                clientGuest,
                inputFieldsValidation
            )
        }
    }
```

This is how looks the screen when the keyboard is opened after an input field is focused/edited:

[image]

Comment: this is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120) of lazy column, please star it

Answer (score 1):

after trying different things with **LazyColumn** and **listState** to scroll to a specific item in the list I decided to left it and instead use a **Column** with vertical scroll because I didn't get it to work properly.

This is how looks like now my scrollable container that replaces the **LazyColumn**

```
Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)
                                .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                        ) {

                            SetupListRowStepper()

                            // Divider wit label
                            DividerWithLabel(LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.you))

                            // list row avatar (Client)
                            ClientProfile()

                            SetupGuestList(
                                coroutineScope,
                                scrollState
                            )

                        }
```

Now we have to perform manual scroll when an input field is focused.
In order to do that we have to interact with **CoroutineScope** and **ScrollState**.

In the item that wraps the inpun field/s get the position of the item in the root 'layout' like this:

```
var scrollToPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0F) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
                scrollToPosition = scrollState.value + layoutCoordinates.positionInRoot().y
            }
    ) {
```

Now when the input field is focused in the card item yo have to perform the scroll like this:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
                        // wait until the keyboard is open
                        delay(100)
                        scrollState.animateScrollTo(
                            scrollToPosition.roundToInt()
                        )
                    }
```

You can experiment with the value of **scrollToPosition** taking account the offset of the input field position, ...

Answer (score 1):

Currently Compose has problems with focus and there persists only a messy workaround:

```
val relocation = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = text,
            modifier = Modifier.bringIntoViewRequester(relocation)
                .onFocusEvent {
                    if (it.isFocused) scope.launch { delay(300); relocation.bringIntoView() }
                },
            onValueChange = ...,
            label = ...,
        )
```

You need to make this for every field, which must be above the keyboard after gaining focus.
Related issues on the issuetracker: [issue #1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205751272), [issue #2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192043120)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody encountering the same issue still:

I was able to solve IME layout issue be simply applying

```
Modifier.imePadding()
```

everywhere you need it. In my case I used a scrollable Column() and had sticky button at the bottom of the screen. Applying imePadding() to the column as well as the button causes both views to scroll up whenever the keyboard is made visible.